# How to do a math function on each row of a forEach loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a table which is created by a forEach loop (loop through a database). what I'm trying to do is to calculate the price by multiplying qty x rate in each row.
I have a JavaScript function(boqMath) to do this, but it only works for the first row(first loop). How can I change it to do this math for every rows(all loops)?

table:

```
<% user.myrates.forEach(function(myrates){ %>

    <tr>
        <td><input type='text' class='form-control' value = "<%= myrates.boqUnit %>"></td>
        <td><input type='text' class='form-control qty' oninput = "boqMath()"></td>
        <td><div class="input-icon"><i>$</i><input type='text' class='form-control rate' oninput="boqMath()" value="<%= myrates.boqRate %>"></div></td>
        <td><div class="input-icon"><i>$</i><input type='text' class='form-control price' oninput="boqMath()"></div></td>
        <td><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button></td>
    </tr>       
<% }); %>
```

and this the function:

```
function boqMath(){

    var a = document.querySelector('.qty').value;
    var b = document.querySelector('.rate').value;
    var price = document.querySelector('.price');
    price.value = (Number(a) * Number(b)).toLocaleString();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the current element to `boqMath()`. From this you can find the closest `tr`, and get the inputs in that row.

```
function boqMath(element) {
    row = element.closest("tr");
    var qty = row.querySelector(".qty").value;
    var rate = row.querySelector(".rate").value;
    var price = row.querySelector(".price");
    price.value = (qty * rate).toLocaleString();
}
```

Change `oninput = "boqMath()">` to `oninput="boqMath(this)"`

Comment: This is good to update all prices, but please note that the OP wants to trigger `boqMath` at `oninput` event

Comment: @Neverever Thanks, updated it for just the current row.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just changed the "rows" to "row" and it worked very well